# Div overflow auto scroll bar middle

Tags: css

I have an image(oversize) need div(overflow:auto) scroll bar place middle

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="img" src="http://www.avis.cr/images/kia_sportage.jpg" />
</div>

#container{
    width:100px; height:100px; 
    overflow:auto; 
    border:solid 1px #000;
}
#img{
    wdith:200px; height:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zuF8r/

Comment: looking to bring your scroll bars to middle ???

Comment: what you are trying to do? scale the image to the size of the container? or display the actual image overriding the container?

Comment: how can it be aligned at center horizontally in such a case? I can't imagine how it should be. This question makes no sense at all.

Comment: ya, i should say scroll bar to middle

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this using pure CSS. You have to use scripts to achieve this result.